# How to convert SubView's Frame Coordinate System to Self View's Coordinate System

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I create programmatically one scrollView and some buttons inside there. When I click the any button have to show a popover.

My button's origin in self.view is like (100,11) and inside scrollView (9,11) and scrowView is in somewhere in self.view. The popover shows in (9,11) but right one would be (100,11). I try use convert without success.

```
-(IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender{
//... implemented popover above

//Wrong Origin:
NSLog(@"wrong x:%f y:%f",[sender frame].origin.x, [sender frame].origin.y);

//Transform to correct
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:[sender frame] toView:nil];

//Shoulf be right, but is not...
NSLog(@"new x:%f y:%f",frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y);
}
```

Anyone cam help me?

Comment: Do you take into consideration scrollView.contentOffset?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

A view's frame is already in the superview's coordinate system. So if your setup is `self.view` contains `scrollview` contains `sender`:

```
CGRect frame = [sender.superview convertRect:sender.frame toView:self.view];

// or, better:

CGRect frame = [sender convertRect:sender.bounds toView:self.view];
```

Comment: and if not? can you share how to make it work on any configuration? I believe it is possible in one line.

Comment: @Andy This will always work when `sender` and `self.view` are members of the same view hierarchy. Otherwise the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 18):

**Swift:**

```
let frame = sender.convert(sender.bounds, to: self.view)
```